# Weird parse crash android - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()

Tags: android, parse-platform

So basically I have tried everything but I keep getting this crash. It crashes only sometimes. Here is my code:

```
if (mCurrentUser != null && mCurrentUser.containsKey(Constants.TABLE_POINTS)) {
    int points = mCurrentUser.getInt(Constants.TABLE_POINTS) + AppSingleton.sPointsLookupMap.get(pointsKey);
                            mCurrentUser.put(Constants.TABLE_POINTS, points);
                            mCurrentUser.saveInBackground();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
at com.titlesource.ts_foodsource.fragments.KitchenFragment$10.done(KitchenFragment.java:654)
at com.titlesource.ts_foodsource.fragments.KitchenFragment$10.done(KitchenFragment.java:649)
at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Now I found that the intValue() is being used inside the getInt() method (Inside the ParseObject class):

```
 public int getInt(String key) {
        Number number = this.getNumber(key);
        return number == null?0:number.intValue();
    }
```

Why am I getting this exception.
 I have tried everything. Added null checks and also verified that the field is actually present in the mCurrentUser object but all in vain.

If down voting this question, please leave a reason.

Comment: One thing is for sure, that exception did not come from the code snippet you showed us. Or at least not in that method, maybe in the getNumber method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have an `Integer` which is null, which you are trying to unbox (making a simple `int` from it).

Since the the `getInt(String key)` method of `ParseObject` already checks if it is null, the exception is not happening there.

Instead, it will be at `AppSingleton.sPointsLookupMap.get(pointsKey)`, so you are trying to get an object from the map which does not exist.

Make sure it exists, or add correct error handling to that part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with this:

```
if (mCurrentUser != null && mCurrentUser.containsKey(Constants.TABLE_POINTS)) {
    int points = mCurrentUser.getInt(Constants.TABLE_POINTS);
    Integer theOtherVariable = AppSingleton.sPointsLookupMap.get(pointsKey);
    if (theOtherVariable != null)
        points += theOtherVariable;
    mCurrentUser.put(Constants.TABLE_POINTS, points);
    mCurrentUser.saveInBackground();
}
```

It should fix the problem and make the code Exception-safe :-)

The first line (after the if) did something like this:

1. You create the `points` variable
2. You assign the `mCurrentUser.getInt(Constants.TABLE_POINTS)` value to it
3. You obtain an `Integer` object with `AppSingleton.sPointsLookupMap.get(pointsKey)`
4. You add the obtained Integer object to `points`, obtaining its value with `.intValue()` call.

All this happened behind the scenes in this one line of code and if the obtained `Integer` object was a null, the `Exception` was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can happen when you pass array of type `Integer` without `final` keyword to the anonymous inner class (for OnClickListener in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error and that's why I'm here. Like said in the accepted answer, code is trying to unbox `Integer` to `int`. And will crash if it's NULL

my code was:

```
private Integer age_limit;

// ...

public int getAge_limit() {
    return age_limit;
  }
```

so changed it to this

```
public Integer getAge_limit() {
    return age_limit;
  }
```

Never knew this would be possible (different data types without any warnings).